# $("#selector").click vs. onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edited as several folks pointed out I'd mixed onchange and onclick ...

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962130/determine-child-most-element-clicked-on-for-javascript-event-datatable-related) yesterday, which someone kindly answered in a way that fixed my problem, but I don't quite get why the `$("#selector").click` methon works but the `onchange=(...)` doesn't.

So if I have HTML, in parent element DataTable cloumn header, where any click in header fires DataTable sort routine:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" onchange="SelectAll(event)">
    SELECT ALL
</div>
```

```js
//This is hit only AFTER the sort routine from the parent element is fired.
function SelectAll(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[name*=\"include_\"]");  //All checkboxes prefixed "include_".       
    var chk = document.getElementById('select_all').checked;

    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if(!boxes[i].disabled) {
            boxes[i].checked = chk;
        }
    }
}

//This is hit BEFORE the sort routine from the parent element is fired.
$("#select_all").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
});
}
```

The second method, fired before the parent element's click event, works for me, but what is the underlying difference between the two?.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattj0nes/y4nhono3/12/)

Comment: you're using onChange event, not onclick. In some browsers onchange is only fired when element loses focus, so onclick will be fired first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onchange` logic you're providing the global `event` object, which is not available in all browsers and is also not 100% guaranteed to be the click event you expect.

For this reason it's best to avoid `on*` event attributes and use an unobtrusive event handler in either native JS or jQuery - exactly as your second JS example is doing. The `event` object passed to the handler function is guaranteed to be the relevant event that contains the information you require.

Also note that the jQuery logic is using a `click` event handler, not a `change`. You should change the `.click()` to a `.change()` so that the event handler still works for those who navigate the web via the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

*onChange* event is usually fired when element loses focus, so *Click* event will be fired first.

Comment: The change event is fired onblur of a text input. For checkboxes it's raised immediately

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use jQuery, ***just use it***. Why do you want to mix up old-school "onxxxx" attributes with this?

Your code is really simple. Just do this instead:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
    SELECT ALL
</div>

function SelectAll( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var chk = $('#select_all')[0].checked;
    $("[name*=\"include_\"]").each( i, element ) {
        if( ! element.disabled ) {
            element.checked = chk;
        }
    }
}

$("#select_all").click( SelectAll );
```

Comment: I take your point. Coming from C/C++ programming I find the syntax of jquery a little less easy to interpret at a glance than native JS. If there's jquery in my code it's usually been provided by someone else. I do intend to convert though, promise.

Comment: If it helps, one thing to keep in mind is that jQuery _is_ native JavaScript. After all, jQuery is simply a JavaScript library. It doesn't introduce any syntax into the JavaScript language that isn't already there: every line of jQuery code is, by definition, a line of JavaScript code. It's not something like [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) that uses a preprocessor to provde its own syntax. You're simply calling functions that are provided by the jQuery library, in the same manner that you might call functions in any other library or in your own code.